# how to fix spss client error：Java VM not found. C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SPSS\STATIS~1\26\JRE\bin\j9vm\jvm.dll initialization routine failed

Tags: spss

I installed spss statistics 26，when I run the application，a client error occurred.It says that java VM not found：jvm.dll initialization routine failed